# Body of IF-statement not executed (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, httpurlconnection, http-status-codes

The body of the IF-statement is never executed. Why is this?

Assume

```
String urlRequest = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Here's my code:

```
try {
        URL url= new URL(urlRequest);
        HttpURLConnection foo = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if(foo.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // SOME CODE HERE
        }

} catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do I need to replace `==` with `.equals()` equivalent for HttpURLConnection? Or do I need to use the status code of the HttpURLConnection instead of the response code?

Comment: This seems fine as I guess its an int value.

Comment: Did you verify you are actually getting a 200 OK response? You might want to print out the response code value for debugging purposes.

Comment: please add `else` condition and check if its goes into that condition.

Comment: @chiragsaga Thanks for that, can't believe I forgot to do add else condition. This helped me realise that a catch exception was being caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body is never getting executed because your code is probably crashing on the HTTP call.
Make sure this call is in a separated thread.
See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html) for more.

As for the actual if statement, seems fine, so its probably an exception issue.

Tbh, In future make sure you provide more info such as Logs and make sure you have done sufficient testing by abstracting code into pieces as stated by @paxdiablo.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, you were absolutely right. My code crashed on the HTTP call as revealed by adding an else{} to my IF-statement and realising that an error showed up in my log. Luckily, your thread suggestion fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you change:

```
if(foo.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
```

into something like:

```
int xyzzy = foo.getResponseCode();
System.out.println ("xyzzy = " + xyzzy);
System.out.println ("   OK = " + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
if(xyzzy == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
```

you should be able to tell why it's not firing.

Chances are, they're *not* equal.